# PDFBox Create Radio Buttons and Checkboxes in java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using pdfbox (1.8.2) in my java project. I need to create a pdf file with a radio buttons and checkboxes. I can find neither any solution for this problem, nor any tutorial. I hope somebody had this problem before and can help me with an andvice or a solution.

thanks=)

Update: Actually there is no opportunity could be found by me. I just painted those boxes on my own.